# Ford Bronco doesn't drive right after front end work

Tags: ford, wheels, alignment, driving, bronco

I just had new upper and lower ball joints, inner and outer tie rods replaced and an alignment on my front end of my 4x4 bronco done.  As I drove it further I noticed a grinding sound as I drove. Also, when I went to apply brakes for a turn then pressed the gas the rpm's went up and the truck didn't move. Then it jerked and started to go forward.

- What could be the cause of this?
- How can it be fixed?

Mind you the hubs on the 4x4 don't work but still drove better then it does now.

Comment: This was not while it was in 4WD? If it was in 4WD when trying to make a corner, the front end *will* bind and the vehicle will not move. Unless the vehicle is setup as an AWD system, it will bind. I know you said your hubs are not working, but if they are engaged without your knowledge, it could be causing your issues. Any more information you can give us?

Comment: I'd skip the internet answers and go directly to the mechanic. Demand that they fix it because thats not normal and a safety issue.

Comment: I agree with Paulster2 it sounds like the front hubs have locked.